# Android volley: Wrong UTF-8 POST encoding

Tags: php, android, encoding, utf-8, android-volley

The code looks like

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, MyPrefs.URL_EMAIL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                displayToast(R.string.toast_email_success);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("name", user.name);
                params.put("surname", user.surname);
                params.put("address", user.address);
                params.put("note", user.note);

                return params;
            }
        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApp.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_order);
```

But problem is, that when I get data into PHP script, they send email that has wrong accent characters, it looks like it doesn't set the email to UTF-8:

```
<?php

$name =      $_POST["name"]; 
$surname =   $_POST["surname"]; 
$address =   $_POST["address"]; 
$note =      $_POST["note"]; 

$to = "test@test.com";

$subject = "TEST";

$message .= "Sender: ".$name." ".$surname."\r\n\n";
$message .= "Address: ".$address."\r\n\n";
$message .= "Note: ".$note."\r\n";

$headers = "From: test@test.com\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
?>
```

And I also set into headers this text and it doesn't help that:

**Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8**

Do you have any advice how to solve that?

Comment: http://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/